# How to fix a file using ffmpeg so that VLC detects Aspect ratio automatically

Tags: ffmpeg, aspect, vlc

I have a video, where the video resolution is 852x480.
When I open it up in VLC, "the Video Aspect" ratio defaults to *Default
However, all I see is a black screen with a thin line as the video!

If I manually change the Aspect ratio to a something other than Default (e.g. 16:9) the video  displays normally.

I've never seen this happen before, why is VLC not detecting the video properly, and why do I  have to change the aspect ratio manually?

What command should I use with ffmpeg to fix it ?

Output of ffmpeg:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SomeLesboMovie (852x480).mp4':   Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2015-08-02T16:17:23.000000Z   Duration: 01:36:06.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2163 kb/s   Stream
#0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 852x480 [SAR 1:270 DAR 71:10800], 1996 kb/s,
29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-02T16:17:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : 264#video:fps=29.97:par=1:270@GPAC0.5.2-DEV-rev387-g3102094-master
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]   Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 162 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-02T16:05:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0] At least one output file must be specified
```

[image]

Comment: Paste the output of `ffmpeg -i FILE`

Comment: @Gyan Thank you for responding, edited to include output of ffmpeg as requested. It seems just by doing the following<code> ffmpeg -i "MyBadMovie(852x480).mp4" -aspect 852:480  -c copy MyFixedMovie.mp4</code> has fixed it, can you please confirm or put the correct answer.

Comment: That's right. Your video was originally tagged as having a display aspect ratio of 71:10800.

Comment: Thank you Gyan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my video by trying the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "MyBadMovie(852x480).mp4" -aspect 852:480 -c copy MyFixedMovie.mp4
```

NB: user @Gyan has confirmed that my display aspect ratio was 71:10800, and I can see this now in the line below, so credit to him for also sharing his expert knowledge.

> #0:00x1: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 852x480 [SAR 1:270 DAR 71:10800], 1996 kb/s,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you NB.  I was able to take a video which always displayed as 4:3 to correctly display in VLC as 16:9 with

ffmpeg -i "1440x1080_video.wmv" -aspect 1920:1080 -c copy 1920x1080_video_fixed.wmv

The file properties still show as 1440x1080, but now plays in VLC with the correct aspect ratio without manually forcing VLC to play it with an AR of 16:9